# Javascript Remove textboxes dynamically added

Tags: javascript, textbox

```
<div id="Bulk_DiV">
        <p>
           <a href="#" id="addBulk" class="link_icon_plus"></a>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="BulkItem[0]_Quantity" size="20" name="BulkItem[0].Quantity" placeholder="Please enter quantity..."/>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="BulkItem[0]_UnitPrice" size="20" name="BulkItem[0].UnitPrice" placeholder="Please enter unit price..."/>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="BulkItem[0]_TotalPrice" size="20" name="BulkItem[0].TotalPrice" placeholder="Please enter total price..."/>
        </p>
    </div>


<script>
         $(function () {
            var bulkDiv = $('#Bulk_DiV');
            var i = $('#Bulk_DiV p').size();

            $('#addBulk').live('click', function () {

                  bulkDiv.append('<p>');
            $('<a>').attr( {
                href: '#',
                id: 'addBulk',
                class: 'link_icon_plus'
            }).appendTo(bulkDiv);

            bulkDiv.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;');

            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'text',
                id: 'BulkItem_Quantity',
                name: 'BulkItem[' + i + '].Quantity',
                size: '20',
                placeholder: 'Please enter quantity...'
            }).appendTo(bulkDiv);

            bulkDiv.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;');

            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'text',
                id: 'BulkItem_UnitPrice',
                name: 'BulkItem[' + i + '].UnitPrice',
                size: '20',
                placeholder: 'Please enter unit price...'
            }).appendTo(bulkDiv);

            bulkDiv.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;');

            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'text',
                id: 'BulkItem_TotalPrice',
                name: 'BulkItem[' + i + '].TotalPrice',
                size: '20',
                placeholder: 'Please enter total price...'
            }).appendTo(bulkDiv);
            bulkDiv.append('&nbsp;&nbsp;');
            $('<a>').attr({
                href: '#',
                id: 'removeBulk',
                name: 'removeBulk',
                class: 'link_icon_minus'
            }).appendTo(bulkDiv);

                bulkDiv.append('</p>');

                i++;
                return false;
            });

            $('#removeBulk').live('click', function () {
                if (i > 1) {
                    $(this).parents("p").remove();
                    i--;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my code, i can add the text box dynamically but i cant remove it although i use .remove(). It suppose work but when i change something in the code, it doesnt work anymore. I cant spot any error there...
All textbox has their own ID in order to get the data.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? `live()` has been deprecated for a very long time. A demo replicating your problem would also help

Comment: It has even been *removed* for two years now.

Comment: You are using `bulkDiv.append('<p>');` and `bulkDiv.append('</p>');` uncorrectly. Instead of wrapping all those textfields and links into paragraph, you create empty paragraph to the beginning and end of your row. And therefore `$(this).parents("p")` doesn't find any matching elements. Unfortunately my jquery skills are bit rusty at the moment and I can't write decent fix - therefore I'm writing this as comment, not as an answer.

Comment: You r right...i just realize that bulkDiv.append('<p>'); and bulkDiv.append('</p>'); is wrong. Anyone can help? I am weak in javascript....

Answer (score 0):

First off, .live is deprecated. Use .on instead. Secondly, I suggest using something like Handlebars templates to create your HTML for each item or otherwise not appending each element one at a time. Appending non breaking spaces is also not a good idea, use CSS to give your elements some spacing.

Instead of using the i variable for counting the indexs, you can just use "BulkItem[].TotalPrice" etc. as the input name. It will convert into an array of items when submitted to the server.

Don't reuse IDs. Use classes instead.

For removing you could use a bubbling event on your container element. This essentially mean "when any element with .item-remove class is clicked inside #Bulk_DiV, remove the closest parent element with the class .item". Delegated events like these allow you to use a single handler instead of attaching one for each element. This allows much better performance with large amounts of elements.

```js
$('#Bulk_DiV').on('click', '.item-remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('.item').remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable explanation. It is helpful for me

Comment: I had a question is how to validate the textboxes dynamically added?